# Showing or Hiding Rows based on Subsequent Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I cobbled together code that hides or shows a range of cells, based on a drop down list of weeks 1 through 5 (i.e. If week 1 is selected, weeks 2-5 are hidden and only cells for week 1 show).

Within each week I have a subsequent drop down selecting options to display rows for the given week, from 1 - 30 rows.

So select a week number to display relevant rows then select a number to select the number of rows shown for given week.

The problem I'm having is that when a given week is selected, all 30 rows for that week are shown again even if previously the user selected to show only rows 1-15.

I understand it's because when a week is selected, only that if statement is checked and the subsequent ones don't run again, but I can't figure out how to rearrange to ensure the subsequent selection is maintained.

I'd like each week to only show the number of rows that the user defined previously, so you can toggle between weeks and see only what was previously selected.

I.e. if a user selects rows 1-15 for week 1, toggles to week 2, and then back to week 1, I only want rows 1-15 to show in week 1, not all 30 rows.

Sample for 'Week 1' below, the sub continues for weeks 2-5 with similar code.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("SELECT_WEEK_FEB").Address Then
        If Target.Value = "Week 1" Then
            Range("WEEK_1_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("WEEK_2_FEB, WEEK_3_FEB, WEEK_4_FEB, WEEK_5_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Week 2" Then
            Range("WEEK_2_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("WEEK_1_FEB, WEEK_3_FEB, WEEK_4_FEB, WEEK_5_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Week 3" Then
            Range("WEEK_3_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("WEEK_1_FEB, WEEK_2_FEB, WEEK_4_FEB, WEEK_5_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Week 4" Then
            Range("WEEK_4_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("WEEK_1_FEB, WEEK_2_FEB, WEEK_3_FEB, WEEK_5_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Week 5" Then
            Range("WEEK_5_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("WEEK_1_FEB, WEEK_2_FEB, WEEK_3_FEB, WEEK_4_FEB").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            
        End If
    End If
    
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' WEEK 1
    If Target.Address = Range("Week_1_Items_Feb").Address Then
        If Target.Value = "1-15" Then
            Range("Feb_Week_1_1_to_15").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("Feb_Week_1_16_to_20, Feb_Week_1_21_to_25,Feb_Week_1_26_to_30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "16-20" Then
            Range("Feb_Week_1_1_to_15, Feb_Week_1_16_to_20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("Feb_Week_1_21_to_25, Feb_Week_1_26_to_30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "21-25" Then
            Range("Feb_Week_1_1_to_15, Feb_Week_1_16_to_20, Feb_Week_1_21_to_25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("Feb_Week_1_26_to_30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
         ElseIf Target.Value = "26-30" Then
            Range("Feb_Week_1_1_to_15, Feb_Week_1_16_to_20, Feb_Week_1_21_to_25, Feb_Week_1_26_to_30").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Where are your drop-downs? Presuming they are on the same sheet as the data, are they in their own column? Both types in the same column? Any other data in those columns? How do you determine the week number? Do you have a date column in your data? are there data for only one month on a sheet?

Comment: Please take a look at this site. https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2013/groups-and-subtotals/1/ I your data would have a column for the week number you could probably do much of the hide-and-seek without code. Imagine a drop-down at the top of your sheet where you select "15" and that is the number of rows shown for every selection. It would be nice if you could post a picture of the top left of your sheet.

Comment: Hi @NorthNorse, in addition to Variatus advice, I'll suggest 2 things. In cases like this where you have multiple If/ElseIf statements, please use the **Select Case** statement (see [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) about this), which will ease the reading and maintainability of your code. Moreover, it seems like you're doing the same operation from week 1 to week 5 (hide or unhide rows). Consider writing a standard _Sub_  and passing the week number as argument.

Comment: @Variatus - Naresh's response below 99% covers what I was looking for. But to answer the other questions: The drop downs are each on the same sheet as the rows being hidden and are separate in their own columns. The months are separated onto their own sheets and weeks are then listed sequentially in ranges on a given month's sheet. 
Thanks for feedback too, much appreciated!

Comment: @Vincent - thanks for the pointers, I will certainly use these going forward!

Comment: @NorthNorse You're welcome ! Don't forget to mark the question as solved (check next to Naresh's answer), so others can benefit from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define all week's range together as "All_Week" then code will be short. Then, you can interlink the two criteria by adding one line to each if condition. 
If you add "All" to "Week_1_Items_Feb" then you can see all the rows for given "SELECT_WEEK_FEB".

Also, I noticed that, you need "Week_1_Items_Feb" to be cumulative. So for 16-20 you need 1-20 output. Then, I would suggest - instead of mentioning it as 16-20 you can mention in like 1-20 in the dropdown list.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("SELECT_WEEK_FEB").Address Then
        Range("All_Week").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If Range("Week_1_Items_Feb").Value = "All" Then
        Range(Target.Value).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
        Range(Target.Value).Rows(Replace(Range("Week_1_Items_Feb").Value, "-", ":")).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

     '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ' WEEK 1

    If Target.Address = Range("Week_1_Items_Feb").Address Then
        Range("All_Week").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If Target.Value = "All" Then
        Range(Range("SELECT_WEEK_FEB").Value).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
        Range(Range("SELECT_WEEK_FEB").Value).Rows(Replace(Target.Value, "-", ":")).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Naresh, this is exactly what I'm looking for and all makes sense. Just a couple of clarifications:

When defining the rows that will be visible per week using: (Target.Value, "-", ":"), is there a way to always include 2 rows above a given weeks items and then the selected number of items? e.g. in your example above, I would like to always show two additional rows above each color block as part of a given week. So if you select say, 1-2, you'd see two rows for headings and then items 1-2?

Comment: Second item, forgive the lack of adaptability...  in example provided above, how might I add a drop down for 'Week_1_items_Feb'  that only controls week 1, and then have subsequent drop downs for week 2, 3, 4 etc (e.g. Week_2_items_Feb)? The example you provided is certainly cleaner, having only one toggle for the number of items, but just interested to know how it might be adapted. Thanks again

Comment: Looking at your comments to the question and the answer, I would suggest to accept this answer and close the question. It would be difficult for anyone to entirely imagine the data and the dropdown lists as there seems to be multiple scenarios you want to be explored. And hence, this will be a very long trail of discussion. Based on this answer and your requirement, you can ask a new question with some sample data/screen shots of your excel sheet and code. Please breakdown your requirements in short questions.